# My bluetooth (sometimes) not working properly recently my speaker started giving wierd grainy noise

Tags: sound, bluetooth, asus

I've installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my laptop which is Asus Tuf FX505DY AMD Ryzen 5, 8GB Ram, 512 GB SSD and 4GB AMD Graphics.

Sometimes bluetooth either not shown or getting disconnected constantly mainly my speaker getting wierd grainy noise. Kindly help me to solve this as i thought linux wud be better than windows and i really feel like windows was better due to high battery consumption.